# Compute $\mathbb{E}[\Phi^n(\mu-\sigma X)]$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF and $X\sim\Phi$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, expected-value

For $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sigma>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ I would like to compute the following expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\Phi^n(\mu-\sigma X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \Phi^n(\mu-\sigma x) \varphi(x) dx,
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF and $\varphi$ is the corresponding density.
For $n=1$ one can derive $\mathbb{E}[\Phi(\mu-\sigma X)] =\Phi(\mu/\sqrt{1+\sigma^2})$ with the approach shown here:
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7505/calculate-the-expectation-of-a-shift-cdf
, but I'm stuck for $n=2,3,...$ since the approach does not generalize nicely (as far as I see). I would be happy for pointers into other directions...

Comment: By $\Phi^n$ do you mean the $n$-fold convolution of $\Phi$?

Comment: I mean the $n$-th power: $\Phi^n(x) = (\Phi(x))^n$